# How to grant SharePoint access to external Organization to perform business operations

Tags: azure, sharepoint

I have a situation in my project work where I need to grant access to an external organization so that the people from the external organization domain Email to whom I share my SharePoint link must be able to access my company-selected SharePoint folder containing specific data to upload certain project-related Excel files. I need to use the External providers submitted file in Azure web services. Please help me out

My expectation is to grant access the SharePoint to an external company so that they can upload certain files.

Comment: provide the approach you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create New Providers Folder in SharePoint:**

1.Please check whether the external organisation to whom you to provide access to your SharePoint has been whitelisted from your domain or not. If not, Please raise a service request to whitelist the domain email of external organization

2. Navigate to SharePoint Home page and then Click on Add List, Libraries and Other apps Icon which shown in below

[image]

3. After Click on above Icon it will be navigate to Site contents --> Your Apps

as shown below

[image]

4. Click on Document library which was shown in above image and Popup will show as below. Enter the Name field, without spaces it should be same as example for e.g. **Name of external organization**

[image]

5. Then click on create button in above image then folder will be created as below with the empty.

[image]

6. You can create a multiple folder against the external Organisation so that can provide/upload their files once permissions are granted.

**Permissions for the folder creation:**
7. Follow the below image and Navigate to Home --> External Organisation folder

[image]

8. After creating a folder for external company in SharePoint If we need to provide any permission to the users follow the below steps. Navigate to settings --> Library settings.

[image]

9. Click on library setting in above image and click on More Library settings as shown in below.

[image]

10. After click on More Library settings below screen will be opened --> Select “Permissions for this document library”.

[image]

11. After click on above selected link it will redirect to permissions page as shown below à and click on Stop Inheriting permissions

[image]

12. After stop inheriting permissions, Now click on Grant Permissions button as shown below

[image]

13. When you click on Select grant permission popup will be opened as below. We need to enter the email address, which was highlighted in red colour, after entering the email id we should not click on share button (highly important don’t click on share button).

[image]

14. If email which was entered is not whitelisted it will be shown as below image.

[image]

15. after entering the email address, in above text box if it will show any message like “Outside of your organization” then the entered email is whitelisted otherwise if you are getting any other message then we need to raise a service request whitelisting of email address.

Click on “Share” so that the invitation and access to the folder can be given to external organisation.